# Local variable is never used warning for foreach loop

Tags: c#, linq

I have written something like this below, `Resharper` says Local variable `refKey` is never used. 
  How Can I make this written a little nicer?

```
  var temp = this.SomeCollection.ToList();
  foreach (var refKey in temp.Where(refKey => this.Teachers.License_key == refKey.ReferenceKey))
  {
      someBool = true;

      this.NotifyPropertyChanged("SomeProperty");
  }
```

Comment: Define Nicer - performance / Elegance / length of lines? Incidentally this wont compile as You use the same variable name "refKey" as the variable and the lambda variable

Comment: You are using the same variable name in the loop variable and the lambda parameter.

Comment: Resharper is telling you that you are making a loop with refkey var, and if you see you ar enever using it! so what is the point!

Comment: @TimSchmelter What's wrong with that?

Comment: well first of all, resharper says refKey isn't used.  Second: if we are setting some bool to true once we find one item that matches the condition then there is no need to loop through the rest of the collection..currently it is

Comment: @Servy: it's at least confusing and error-prone. However, the variable names are weird anyway. I hope it's just because of the "simplification".

Comment: @TimSchmelter Fair enough.  I though you were going to say it wasn't legal C# and was prepared to throw [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/05/simple-names-are-not-so-simple-part-two.aspx) at you.  But yes, confusing it is indeed.

Comment: When your code is working and you only need to improve it, please post the question on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Suppose there are fifty keys that match that predicate; do you really want `NotifyPropertyChanged` called fifty times?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It appears that what you want to do is execute some code if there are any items in that query, rather than executing those lines of code for every item in the query.  The `Any` method allows you to do this more effectively:

```
if(temp.Any(refKey => this.Teachers.License_key == refKey.ReferenceKey))
{
    someBool = true;
    this.NotifyPropertyChanged("SomeProperty");
}
```